# How to invoke java method with a few parameters inside spring app context xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I try to configure my spring app.
And I need to define property placeholder like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:ov.properties,file:#{appServerUrl.replaceFirst('regexp','')}/test.properties"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

But in result I have `org.springframework.expression.ParseException: Expression 'file:#{appServerUrl.replaceFirst(''' @ 5: No ending suffix '}' for expression starting at character 5`
If I invoke java method with one parameter only or without parameters, it works correctly. What's wrong? Thank you for reply.

Comment: After debugging a few spring classes I found that a comma character between `replaceFirst('','')` method parameters spoils parsing. Spring separate it on two locations `"file:#{appServerUrl.replaceFirst('regexp'"` and  `"'')}/test.properties"`

Comment: you can use init-method and destroy-method to call method when the bean is created or destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser for the `<context:property-placeholder/>` elements first splits the value of the `location` attribute using `StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(String)`. That is why is splits your second location in two.

To circumvent that, you could define a `String` bean with the value of your second location:

```
<bean name="testPropertiesLocation" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="file:#{appServerUrl.replaceFirst('regexp','')}/test.properties" />
</bean>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:ov.properties,#{testPropertiesLocation}"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, I found it in Spring source code. Thank you for this simple and clear solution.